# GoToMeetingand Google Docs integration with sugarcrm

Tags: php, sugarcrm, google-docs-api

Can I pull google docs to the documents module of sugarcrm?
Similarly can I pull meetings from GoToMeeting to the meetings module of sugarcrm?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

With the commercial editions of SugarCRM, you can integrate google docs and webex and goto meeting and a bunch of lotus items